# A CNC machine for PCB manufacturing

Tags: pcb, soldering, tools, cnc

I'm looking for a CNC machine that can be used for different PCB manufacturing tasks such as:

- Drilling PCBs (using a rotating head)
- Pick and place (to assemble PCBs)
- Soldering

This CNC does not have to be heavy-duty, I'm just looking for some decent accuracy to deal with SMD parts.

- A while ago I found the [Lumenlab Micro CNC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk7txUHU7Ho) which was modular and multi-function, but they seem to have stopped production.
- The [RepRap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RepRap_Project) seems to be a 3D printer only, I don't think you can do anything else with it.
- The [Makerbot](http://store.makerbot.com/replicator-404.html) is another 3D printer.
- The [ShopBot Desktop](http://www.shopbottools.com/mProducts/desktop.htm#routerpkg) is a multi-function CNC and lathe, but only for drilling/plotting/engraving.
- The [redFrog PnP machine](http://buildyourcnc.com/PickandPlaceMachineTheredFrog.aspx) is a low cost hobbyist Pick n Place machine that works for SMD parts. About the lowest cost machine you can find.
- The [OpenPnP project](http://code.google.com/p/openpnp/) documents an incomplete Pick n Place design. But you must build it yourself, nothing to buy here.

Comment: They're three different machines, and soldering isn't done with an iron, but reflow in a carefully temperature controlled oven. The P&P is a tall order, literally. How much do you want to spend? I got a quote of 35 000 dollar for [this small machine](https://www.manncorp.com/pick-and-place/mc400/?auto=done).

Comment: I have not seen any soldering XYZ machines, do they exist? Solder paste dispensers do exist, and would seem more usefull for an SMD prototyping environment. About P-n-P machines: the big problem is not so much the XYZ movements, but the pickup/release mechanism and the component dispensers. I think SMD needs more than the 'decent' accuracy that is acceptable for hobby 3D printers.

Comment: Have you seen a P&P machine that can also be used as a simple CNC?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - Yes, they do exist. Here is a [Micro Laser Soldering System](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnyB9btlhS8).

Comment: If you want to make a PnP machine yourself, it's not impossible. Lots of people have done it. Take a look at the [OpenPnP project](http://code.google.com/p/openpnp/).

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - does this pick the parts from tape and reel? If I watch the simulation it looks like components are nicely lined up, and then I might as well drop them directly onto the board IMO.

Comment: @Steven - yes it does. If you watch the [partial board test](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPHi1JaWPJM&feature=channel&list=UL) you can see it picking (slowly) from the reel. It looks pretty good though considering the project has only been active for a year. Be interesting to keep an eye on.

Comment: Milling generally requires leadscrews for rigidity, which introduces rotating mass if you want to then move fast enough to pick and place - PCB milling is up to ~20mm/s and pick and place ~1000mm/s. Unless the machine is so tiny it has no mass, or is very slow at placing, you have to design it to work well for a factor of 100 in speed. (Cirquoid uses leadscrews and has max feed of 20mm/s, so takes several seconds to fetch components 100mm away on its bed)

Answer (score 4):

As @stevenh said, they are 3 separate machines.

1. I can't answer.
2. At work we have a pick and place machine. It's pretty specialized since it has to take parts from various tubes and trays. As @stevenh said, this is an expensive machine. I wouldn't try that with a general CNC machine.
3. Soldering by machine is done by wave or reflow. A soldering iron is likely not what you want. If you are a hobbyist, consider a toaster oven for reflow solution.

Comment: -0.33 for #1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know two systems which are made for small size prototyping ("low-cost").

1. [Cirqoid](http://cirqoid.com/)

   - can mill, dispense solder paste and place the components
2. [voltera](http://www.voltera.io/) (shall be delivered in the end of 2016)

   - can print a two layer pcb, dispense solder paste and bake the board

Disclaimer: I do not work for either of these projects.

Comment: If you're not working for one of the projects, are you working for the other one?

Comment: @PeteKirkham - C'mon, its quite clear that english is not his first language. He means to say "I am not working for **even** one of **these** projects". Corrections in italics.

Comment: y, I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what your asking. The FirePick Delta is built using the openPnP project that has already been linked. It is an ongoing project but it might be of interest to you. https://hackaday.io/project/963-firepick-delta-the-open-source-microfactory